# Load resource file from dependency in Codename One

Tags: ant, jar, resources, inputstream, codenameone

I know that with `Resources.getData("resourcepath")` i could load some resource in my code. But what happens if you need to load some resource that its located in jar dependency. Its very important for me to keep it there and not in my `theme.res`: cause this dependency contains interfaces and resources i wanna share among projects, so i may keep consistency between the enviroments (mobile and web).
I dont know very well how **Ant** works with Codename One, maybe altering my `build.xml` i may copy this resource in a way it be easy to load it from the classpath, or maybe already exists a way to load it from the `src/main/resources` folder of my dependency. So, i need a way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't work with jar dependencies in Codename One. You need to use [cn1lib's](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html) either your own or made by 3rd party.

This is discussed rather in depth [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

You can load a resource file from a different file name than the default but not from a different directory. You can download it directly from the internet etc.

Comment: So it seems that the only way would be creating a  cn1lib project for adding aditional functionalities. But right now i am working with a Jar, but maybe because i just use interfaces?

Comment: You can hack jars to work but we don't officially support that since there are too many things that you could do incorrectly and only find out about later with odd server build errors.